# Get first row in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to return the first row in mysql result

I have a query with order by resulting in 3 rows to be returned but i only want to return the first row

```
select nondox
     , account
     , id 
  from rates2test 
 where weight = 1 
   and country_code='AF' 
   and service='INT' 
 order 
    by nondox asc 
 limit 1
```

**Table**

```
 nondox, account, id
'51.47', '610533699', '2'
'51.47', '610798706', '950042'
'51.47', '610662766', '1941032'
```

Expected: should return first row
Actual: Returns the last row

Comment: "should return first row" - And what makes it "first row"?

Comment: I want to sort by nondox to get the cheapest rate and then if the nondox values are same, i want to return the row with account 610533699

Comment: Good grief: Order by nondox, account

Comment: And what makes "account 610533699" the first of three? Note: Your question should be as clear as possible. Don't let us guess.

Comment: Thanks  Order by nondox, account  works. account 610533699 is first because it comes as first in the list and also has the lowest id number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  account asc in order by

```
 select nondox, account, id from 
 rates2test where weight='1' 
 and country_code='AF' and service='INT' 
 order by nondox asc,account asc limit 1
```

Comment: I want to return the cheapest rate, so order by nondox is required. But then if the rates(nondox) are same, then i want to return the row with acocunt 610533699